# Testing web layer Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, testing

Just made a controller in Spring Boot and I want to unit test it.

The code of the controller and its method is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/projects/{pid}/clusters")
public class ClusterController {

    @Autowired
    private ClusterService clusterService;

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllClusters(@PathVariable("pid") Integer projectId, Model model){
        Project project = this.projectService.getProjectById(projectId);
        Set<Cluster> clusters = project.getClusters();
        model.addAttribute("projectID", projectId);
        model.addAttribute("clusters", clusters);
        return "clusters";
    }
```

This method simply returns a view (HTML) when a user gets to a specific URL.

Code of my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class clusterControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private URL base;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
    }

    @Test
    public void getCluster() throws Exception{
        this.base = new URL("http://localhost:" + port + "/projects/1/clusters");
        ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity(base.toString(), String.class);
        assertThat(response.getBody(), equalTo("clusters"));

    }
}
```

I'm already testing my repository and service layer in other tests. I only want to get the right return when navigating to a specific URL (which calls a specific method in de Controller).

In my examply when someone goes to "http://localhost:" + port + "/projects/1/clusters" The Controller should return "clusters".

When I execute this code I get the error that says my assertThat went wrong. Because "clusters" is compared to the whole html page.

How can I easily just test the return string of my controller?
I don't have much experience with testing. 
Much thanks in advance!

### Edit

```
@RunWith(MockitoRunner.class)
public class clusterControllerTest {
    // inject any dependencies as mocks
    ClusterController testee = new ClusterController();

    @Test
    public void getCluster() {
        String returnedViewName = testee.getCluster();
        assertThat(returnedViewName).isEqualTo("clusters"));
        // Hurray, it worked, but does it verify anything? Nope.
    }
}
```

Used the advice of one of the comments to test it and getting return type.
But In my Controller class i give Model model as a parameter. How can I give this to the controller in the test? Simply Model model as a parameter doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest to use MockMvc or RestAssured for testing Web layer.

**MockMvc:**

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html

Example of MockMvc:

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

**RestAssured:**

- http://rest-assured.io/

Examples of RestAssured:

- https://g00glen00b.be/spring-boot-rest-assured/
- https://blog.jayway.com/2014/01/14/unit-testing-spring-mvc-controllers-with-rest-assured/

Comment: I already looked at MockMvc at the first link and tried it. It then gives me errors because my Cluster Entity has some relationships with other Entities and is using LazyLoading

Answer (score 0):

By verifying whether your controller's method returns the name of the particular view you're *not* really testing the web layer on its integration level, but the implementation detail of how Spring MVC works.

If you want to do a proper web-level test you can test for some properties of the resulting that will be enough to verify the page-creating logic worked, e.g. contains some specific string:

```
// (...)
assertThat(response.getBody(), contains("\"clusters\""));
```

Or use JsonPath to verify the contents on the JSON level, verifying the structure and/or the values themselves.

The dependencies (i.e. services and repositories) that are already tested somewhere else should mocked, for instance using the convenient [MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) annotation.

---

If you *really* want to verify your controllers work on the "code" level (which would not add much value), you could simplify your test to:

```
@RunWith(MockitoRunner.class)
public class clusterControllerTest {
    // inject any dependencies as mocks
    ClusterController testee = new ClusterController();

    @Test
    public void getCluster() {
        String returnedViewName = testee.getCluster();
        assertThat(returnedViewName).isEqualTo("clusters"));
        // Hurray, it worked, but does it verify anything? Nope.
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what your idea is and mine and the differences. But as I said I'm already testing all the other layers like Repo and Service. All my controller methods simply calls methods from the service layers that are tested. What would make more sense in my situation to test?

Comment: You could use Mockito and [Spies](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Spy.html), [verify](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1) internal calls to dependencies but this would not be a good controller test - it would break as soon as you changed your implementation (even if the HTTP response from the controller was unchanged)

Comment: So in other words, it doesn't make much sense to test the controller level? As it's only task in my project is to call methods in other layers